# Facebook Graph API collect posts only recently updated

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am currently collecting all page posts via the api using the since parameter i.e.

```
12345678910/feed?since=[LastCheckTimeUnix]
```

However I need to know if any earlier posts have been updated, using the updated_time field.

The only way I can see is to collect every post ever posted and then check the updated_time. However this is obviously inefficient. Is there a way to obtain all posts with an updated_time > LastCheckTime?

Comment: Any luck on this @SSED?

Comment: No it can't currently be done. I maintain a last check time locally and then compare the updated_time to this to find out if the post has been edited or a comment added/edited - if so I then process. Problem is having to trawl through all previous posts and deciding how far back to go.